# undo/redo plugin for nicEditor(having multiple instance on a page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nicedit

I have a page having multiple instance of niceditor.
I want to create an undo/redo button which is specific to the text area.
Cant use exec command.

Comment: and what have you tried? where did you encounter problems? we're not going to write the whole thing for you.

Comment: rit now i am using 3 editors on one page so i have taken 3 arrays. I push the content of the div on key press.so I want to know if thr is any other way to do it for the three editors